# Ansible + JMESPath: Return name of key when contains matches against nested data

Tags: ansible, jmespath

Source data is JSON dictionary where top-level key names are not predictable. I need the name of that TL key when nested data inside matches a string I have.

I am attempting this using a the json_query filter inside Ansible 2.9.

I have tried various JMESPath queries and searched through their documentation, but everything I have found appears to require knowing the names of those keys ahead of time.

Here is sample data - which is output from ansible ios_facts module against interfaces:

```
{
        "GigabitEthernet0/9": {
            "description": "server",
            "ipv4": [],
            "macaddress": "b8zz.xxxx.7709",
            "type": "Gigabit Ethernet"
        },
        "Vlan13": {
            "description": null,
            "ipv4": [
                {
                    "address": "10.20.30.19",
                    "subnet": "24"
                }
            ],
            "macaddress": "b8zz.xxx.yy41",
            "type": "EtherSVI"
        }
}
```

Here is playbook I am working with:

```
---
- name: Cisco IOS - Mgmt Int
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: switch01
  vars:
     netdb: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_net_interfaces'] }}"
  tasks:
    - name: get ios facts
      ios_facts:
        gather_subset: interfaces
    - name: json_query
      set_fact:
        mgmtinf: "{{ netdb | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        # this gets me true/false
        query: "[Vlan13.ipv4[0].address.contains(@, '10.20.30.19')]"
    - name: output json_query
      debug:
        var: mgmtinf
```

The above works to return true/false if the result matches. The problem is that I have manually defined the interface to look at 'Vlan13'. So I need a way to use an iterator for that TL key, and then return value of that iterator at the part in the loop where match occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give all your requirements to select the matching key name but the following should put you on track.

The key points:

- Use the [`dict2tems` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) to transform the top level dict to a list of `{key: X, value: Y}` objects
- Use jmespath to:

  1. Filter out the elements corresponding to vlans (I used "Vlan*" in my example)
  2. Filter out the list of ips for each `ipv4` elements to match only your desired IP.

**Note**: The `to_json | from_json` in my expression is necessary to overcome a [current bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299) in the communication between ansible and jmespath (string types mapping).

Here is a sample task illustrating the above scenario.

```
    - name: Filter out specific ip elements on my vlans
      vars:
        vals: {
          "GigabitEthernet0/9": {
            "description": "server",
            "ipv4": [],
            "macaddress": "b8zz.xxxx.7709",
            "type": "Gigabit Ethernet"
          },
          "Vlan13": {
            "description": null,
            "ipv4": [
            {
              "address": "10.20.30.19",
              "subnet": "24"
            }
            ],
            "macaddress": "b8zz.xxx.yy41",
            "type": "EtherSVI"
          }
        }
        query: >-
          [?starts_with(key, 'Vlan')].value.ipv4[] | [?contains(address, '10.20.30.19')]
      debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ vals | dict2items | to_json | from_json | json_query(query) }}
```

And the result I get with your current values:

```
TASK [Filter out specific ip elements on my vlans] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "address": "10.20.30.19",
            "subnet": "24"
        }
    ]
}
```